# Purpose of PureAttribute on parameter

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, code-contracts

I understand that the [`PureAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is used to mark something (class, method, delegate etc.) as making no visible changes, but I can see from the following definition that it can be applied to method parameters:

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Class|AttributeTargets.Constructor|AttributeTargets.Method|AttributeTargets.Property|AttributeTargets.Event|AttributeTargets.Parameter|AttributeTargets.Delegate, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class PureAttribute : Attribute
```

What is the purpose of this attribute being applied to a parameter, such as in the following:

```
public void SomeMethod([Pure]SomeClass theParameter)
{
}
```

Does it imply that `SomeMethod` should not use anything on `theParameter` which is not marked as `[Pure]`, meaning we can ensure the instance of `SomeClass` visibly appears the same before and after the invocation of `SomeMethod`?

I have not seen the `PureAttribute` used in this way and was wondering if this is due to lack of support in code contracts or because of a misunderstanding of mine?

Comment: Classes are reference types, the method could alter a field or property of *theParameter* and that change is observable outside of the method.  The [Pure] attribute promises that the method doesn't do this.  A substitute for the *const* keyword in the C and C++ languages.

Comment: @HansPassant If you could put your comment as an answer I would be happy to accept it. It seems to be what I had assumed, however I could find nowhere which explicitly stated this, the MSDN only mentions `[Pure]` being applied to methods and types. Do you by any chance have a link to any documentation which clarifies this purpose when applied to parameters?

Comment: @HansPassant If it's the method which is doing the change it shouldn't that be stated by applying a `PureAttribute` to `SomeMethod` instead of the parameter?

Comment: @Albireo I think Hans is saying that the method guarantees not to invoke any impure methods on `theParameter`, however `SomeMethod` may make some impure changes itself, i.e. `theParameter` will have no changes but other things may.

Comment: Applying [Pure] on the method means something else afaik, it promises that it won't change the observable state of the *this* object.  I should write it up but don't have quite the time to do it properly right now.  Maybe later.

Comment: @HansPassant I thought the `[Pure]` attribute signified that it does not change any visible state of anything, hence it is safe to use the attributed method in a `Contract.Requires` or `Ensures` call (which may or may not be executed depending upon options). If it allowed some visible side affects on other things, the inclusion/exclusion of `Contract.Requires` at runtime could change the behavior of the application.

Answer (score 5):

The `PureAttribute`, as you stated, indicates that a type or method is pure, that is, it does not make any visible state changes (taken straight from the MSDN article).

Maybe your `SomeClass` is not marked as pure because it *can* change the state, however it does not mean that everything in it is impure.

Maybe your `SomeMethod` doesn't use any of `SomeClass` impure methods, maybe it simply reads its properties (I'm assuming you're not performing impure action in property getters, otherwise you're evil), so its usage of `SomeClass` is pure.­­­­­

Comment: I wasn't the one to downvote. However as my question states I do understand the purpose of the `PureAttribute` and use it almost daily, what I am after is some clarification of its purpose when applied to a parameter.

Comment: @Lukazoid yes, I initially misread your question and I've updated my answer. Did you read the initial version or the updated one?